# Regex escaping question

Tags: php, regex

How can I escape the $ in the replaced section in the following statement?

```
$tmp_code = preg_replace('/(<\?=\$([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\?>)/me','"{$$2}"',$tmp_code);
```

The replaced text should like like {$test} however I can't figure out how to escape the first $. I've tried \$ but that didn't do anything.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=preg_replace+escape+dollar ?

Comment: What the `$tmp_code` contains before that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should prefer [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) over the `/e` expression modifier. But depending on what you want to do, there are multiple workarounds.

You can split up the string expression:

```
 '"{"."$"."$2"."}"', $tmp
```

Or use the alternative placeholder syntax and escape the `{$` so it does not get interpreted as variable variable within the double quotes:

```
 '"{\\\$\2}"'
```

(No, I didn't know that. Just tinkered around.)